# Height and Width of path data

Tags: wpf, path, height, width

I am new to `WPF` and have a `Path` data like:

`M44.3364,36.7461C42.2004,42.9021,36.3504,47.3241,29.4644,47.3241C20.7724,47.3241,13.7244,40.2761,13.7244,31.5851`

Now I want to get height and width of this path data, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get the [`Bounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.bounds.aspx) of the Path's `Data`:

```
<Path x:Name="path" Stroke="Black"
      Data="M44.3364,36.7461C42.2004,42.9021,36.3504,47.3241,29.4644,47.3241C20.7724,47.3241,13.7244,40.2761,13.7244,31.5851"/>
```

Code:

```
Rect bounds = path.Data.Bounds;
```